# Overloading on (desired) return type

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

It's easy to define a `to_string` function for your own types, and *simply* call it via overloading.  The bulk of the code knows the convention that `to_string(x)` will be found via ADL and templates can rely on that without knowing the type of `x`.

But what about the opposite, such as a `from_string` function?  What is a **good** way for types to supply their own implementations, such that other code can *easily* and *conveniently* call it, and it can work in templates as well?

Using a single template with explicit specializations for each type run into headaches when these implementations are themselves generic to some group of types.  (At least, it was so in pre-Concept implementations.)

Making the desired type appear in the parameter list, either as a dummy argument or via a template type wrapping the input string, has the advantage that the selection of the function uses proper overload resolution and can simply and naturally choose between different implementations, including plain single-type functions, templates that handle some group of related types, implicit conversions, and inheritance relationships.

While it works for generic code, it is awkward to call and I don't want to make that the normal way of invoking it.

My project uses gcc 8, which has C++17 support plus the Concepts TS.  The standard library doesn't know anything about Concepts, but I can use `requires` and create concepts in my own code.

What would be a good way to define a function like this `from_string`?

Comment: Why not a static member of the class you are converting into.  `staitc Blah Blah::from_string(std::string const& stream);` Usage: `Blah x = Balh::from_string(input);`

Comment: @MartinYork a lot of the types are enums.

Answer (score 3):

To support template classes, you need a struct that can be specialized.

```
template<class T, class sfinae=void> struct from_string_impl;
```

And then a helper method and type to invoke its `operator()`:

```
struct from_string_t {
   const std::string& str;
   template<class T>
   operator T() const {return from_string_impl<T>{}(str);}
};
from_string_t from_string(const std::string& str) {return {str};}
```

And a few basic starter implementations:

```
template<> struct from_string_impl<int>{int operator()(const std::string& str) { return std::stoi(str);}};
template<> struct from_string_impl<long>{long operator()(const std::string& str) { return std::stol(str);}};
template<> struct from_string_impl<long long>{long long operator()(const std::string& str) { return std::stoll(str);}};
template<> struct from_string_impl<unsigned long>{unsigned long operator()(const std::string& str) { return std::stoul(str);}};
template<> struct from_string_impl<unsigned long long>{unsigned long long operator()(const std::string& str) { return std::stoull(str);}};
template<> struct from_string_impl<float>{float operator()(const std::string& str) { return std::stof(str);}};
template<> struct from_string_impl<double>{double operator()(const std::string& str) { return std::stod(str);}};
template<> struct from_string_impl<long double>{long double operator()(const std::string& str) { return std::stold(str);}};
```

Usage is trivial in most cases:

```
int i = from_string("304.5");
double d = from_string("304.5");
unsigned long long ull = from_string("304.5");
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4bd08dbe081a156

Though you'll get compiler errors if you try to pass it to a method that itself have overloads, as the compiler will be unable to deduce what type to convert the return type to.

Interestingly, this works just fine all the way back to when templates were first added to C++.

Comment: Your class template should probably have an extra, defaulted template parameter for SFINAE purposes.

Comment: That's just how you had to make explicit specialization of template functions before that was allowed to do directly.  It has exactly the same drawbacks that I explained in the OP.  I do in fact have an `operator T()` helper like you show!  But the underlying thing that calls is (currently) using the dummy argument to support overloading, *because* of the issues with specializing the template as explained in the OP.

Comment: For example, many of your "basic starter implementations" are actually a single template for integral types.   Another template is for enum-based strong types, but I still need specific implementations for some of the enum-based types that need special handling.  Overloading will pick the regular function over the template; specializations would be awkward to keep the enable_ifs mutually exclusive.

Comment: @JDługosz: I'm struggling to understand the issue. Can you give an example of some of these enum-based strong types, so I can see why this is hard?

Comment: @MooingDuck yes, I'll expand it when I'm less busy getting.